# Why "http:" and "https:" is not shown in Laravel 5.8 results?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm wondering why Laravel can't show `http:` and `https:` in returned results ?

```
Route::get('test', function () {
return 'http://test https://';
}) ;
```

The code above returns : `//test //` instead to returns :`http://test https://`

At the same time when I : `dd('training https: test after adding the permission: https')` it returns the string without problems as you can see here `training https: test after adding the permission: https` (http: and https: are present).

**PHP** : when I `php -r "echo 'http://test https://';"` I dont have this problem and the result is :`http://test https://`.

**important :**

- This problem is only on production server! I don't have this problem on my local environment.
- The problem is only with these two strings `http:` and `https:`

**Server specifications :**

```
PHP Version => 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, pgsql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 3591daad22de08524295e1bd073aceeff11e6579 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

pdo_pgsql

PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version => 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
Module version => 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Revision =>  $Id: 9c5f356c77143981d2e905e276e439501fe0f419 $

pgsql

PostgreSQL Support => enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version => 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
PostgreSQL(libpq)  => PostgreSQL 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit
Multibyte character support => enabled
SSL support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pgsql.allow_persistent => On => On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent => Off => Off
pgsql.ignore_notice => Off => Off
pgsql.log_notice => Off => Off
pgsql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
pgsql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It's not about Laravel, but your server. What's your webserver?

Comment: service apache2 status
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset:
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf

Answer (score -2):

Thats a good question but it's not the right place to put the https

```
//file: app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        if (app()->environment('remote')) {
            URL::forceSchema('https');
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: here the Env: APP_ENV=test

Answer (score -2):

If you're trying to make this work while you are using laravel 6.x, Try the following: 
In the AppserviceProvider.php File

```
// AppServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

Comment: I use Laravel 5.8

Comment: Have you tried it that should also work in 5.8+ versions

Comment: I'ts not about  https in url !